# Is there anyway to resize textures?

Tags: rendering, optimization

My file size is quite large and takes forever to load all images into vram. I used a lot of ~3K PBR textures found on poliigon and I wish I used 1K textures instead. Is there anyway to select the textures of materials I want to resize and downscale them inside blender? Or similar workflow?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the object that has the image that you need to change from the viewport.
- Go to the Editor Type and select **Image Editor** or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Make sure the image is inside the square and go to **Image > Resize**

[image]

Hope that's what you are looking for.