# How to change level of detail of an image texture like in C4D?

Tags: texturing, image, displacement, normal-map

In this C4D tutorial, the artist changes the level of detail of the texture to 4k. Is there a way to do this in Blender? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Texture in blender is set to "no limit" by default, so you have the highest quality and all depends on your image size. If you wanna change that down to something smaller, you need to go to the Render settings > Simplify > Viewport > Texture limit.

[image]

That option in c4d is for the viewport to display a better quality texture

Comment: Thank you for sharing that: I was not aware of texture limit. Is there a way to increase the resolution of a single image texture in node editor?

Comment: Your texture resolution depends on your texture original size. You could try to make it smaller like [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/is-there-anyway-to-resize-textures/191397#191397)

Comment: I tried that but they still appear low quality. Maybe im missing a step? I'm pretty new. Could you possibly try following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FpF3ggJ43g&t=205s) and see if you can mimic it in blender?

Comment: You should open a new question to describe the issue that you are having with the texture been render in low resolution, make sure to add your image of the viewport render and also your render settings. What the tutorial is showing is just changing C4D viewport level of detail from low to high not changing the texture size. also, make sure to use Cycles Render